# Bluetooth using Plugin.BLE to get serial port for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to establish a connection to a BLE device from a xamarin forms app using the plugin.Ble library.
The device that I am connecting to is sending a constant stream of position data, which I can see using other (not made by me) apps which connect to the device and shows "the console".

Using Plugin.BLE I can successfully query devices, connect and see their services and characteristics, but I cannot find a characteristics with data stream and I cannot see how to connect to the serial port protocol using Plugin.BLE

Does this library even support this serial port protocol? Is there a characteristic which is known to link to the serial interface?

Alternatively, if someone can suggest a more suitable library which can work for both android and Ios through Forms, that is equally fine, as I am just starting to add the bluetooth functionality.

Comment: Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to look at the offered services and characteristics of your device. If it is sending a constant stream of data there should be one characteristic that allows enabling of notifications/indications (shown by a symbol of three downward arrows). This is the characteristic you want to subscribe to using forms

Comment: It may not be an exact answer for my question but it sure looks like it is the answer that I needed. There is indeed an unnamed characteristic which streams data, and it looks like it is the data I need. Comes as hex and not ascii, so I need to verify, but that was a really good tip!

Comment: My problem is similar to this. In Jquery app they send reading command with hex number 0xAA 0xC1 0xF0 .. ... ... ..  to get a notification.  but how can we do this in Plugin.BLE ? sorry I am quite new to xamarin forms